# set div data attribute using a code behind value in an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-data-attribute

On an .aspx page I need to set the data-attribute on a addthis div.
The value is an URL that is calculated in the code behind.

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="CodeBehindValue"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.

**Using a property**

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="<%= PropertyFromCodeBehind %>"></div>
```

**Using a method**

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="<%= MethodFromCodeBehind() %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you choose your `div` to run at the server (`runat="server"`) such as:

```
<div id="divMyID" class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="CodeBehindValue" runat="server"></div>

divMyID.Attributes("data-url") = "http://www.test.com"
```